# Use Confluent CLI in order to run several kafka brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform, broker

I wasn't able to find an answer for this, and I'm facing some difficulties while trying to implement it.

Does confluent command only is able to run multiple brokers + Zookeeper?
Is it possible to build a kafka cluster consist of 3 nodes, using Confluent CLI?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not support multi-node clusters.

It only runs a single localhost `kafka-server-start` and `zookeeper-server-start` commands.

Additionally, as mentioned on the documentation page

> meant for development purposes only and is not suitable for a production environment. The data that are produced are transient and are intended to be temporary.

By "production environment" here, it is implied as multiple servers.